# Setting 0,0 as the origin in a c3 graph (eliminating padding)

Tags: graph, padding, c3.js

I am using c3 to make a graph and I am looking to get the origin of the graph to be 0,0 without any padding. With this code I have my y-axis right on the line (x-axis), but on the x axis there is still a gap between the 0 tick mark and the y axis.

I tried a couple different things and it looks like the padding works differently for the two axes. Is there something I can fix in my code to get rid of all padding on the left of X and?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
                padding: {
                    top: 4,
                    right: 150,
                    bottom: 4,
                    left: 150,
                },
                data: {
                    x: 'x',
                    columns: [
                                ['x', 0, intersect, intersect, xinterceptd/2, xinterceptd],
                                ['demand curve', yinterceptd, (1*yinterceptd)+(1*demandslope*1*intersect), (1*yinterceptd)+(1*demandslope*1*intersect), yinterceptd/2 , 0],
                                ['supply curve', yintercepts, supplyslope*intersect + (1*yintercepts), supplyslope*intersect + (1*yintercepts), (supplyslope*xinterceptd*1)/2 + (1*yintercepts), supplyslope*xinterceptd + (1*yintercepts)],
                                ['equilibrum price', supplyslope*intersect + (1*yintercepts), supplyslope*intersect + (1*yintercepts), null, null, null],
                                ['equilibrum quantity', null, 0, supplyslope*intersect + (1*yintercepts), null, null]
                    ],
                    regions: {
                        'equilibrum price': [{'style':'dashed'}], 
                        'equilibrum quantity': [{ 'style':'dashed'}]
                }},
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        label: xunits,
                        padding: {left: 0},
                        min: 0
                    },
                    y: {
                        label: yunits, 
                        padding: {bottom: 0},
                        min: 0
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks